# Finding lowest and highest relative strength index for StochRSI formula

Tags: c#

I wanted to optimize the following code in terms of better looking code. The code is finding lowest and highest value used for StochRSI formula. An example might be using LINQ or a different data structure.

```
List<decimal> rsis = new List<decimal>();

decimal lowestLow = 1000000000000000m;
decimal highestHigh = -1000000000000000m;

decimal[] rsi = CalculateRSI(prices, 14);

for (int i = 1; i < price.Length; ++i)
{
    rsis.Insert(0, rsi[i]);
    if (rsi[i] > highestHigh)
        highestHigh = rsi[i];
    if (rsi[i] < lowestLow)
        lowestLow = rsi[i];
    if (rsis.Count > rsiLength)
    {
        decimal last = rsis[rsis.Count - 1];
        rsis.RemoveAt(rsis.Count - 1);
        if (last >= highestHigh || last <= lowestLow)
        {
            lowestLow = 1000000000000000;
            highestHigh = -1000000000000000;
            for (int l = 0; l < rsis.Count; l++)
            {
                if (rsis[l] > highestHigh)
                    highestHigh = rsis[l];
                if (rsis[l] < lowestLow)
                    lowestLow = rsis[l];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what `decimal[] rsi` is. It would be nice if you know a way not to recalculate the entire thing everytime there is a new price added to `decimal[] price`.

```
public decimal[] CalculateRSI(decimal[] price, int period)
{
    var rsi = new decimal[price.Length];

    decimal gain = 0m;
    decimal loss = 0m;

    rsi[0] = 0m;

    for (int i = 1; i <= period; ++i)
    {
        var diff = price[i] - price[i - 1];
        if (diff >= 0)
        {
            gain += diff;
        }
        else
        {
            loss -= diff;
        }
    }

    decimal avrg = gain / period;
    decimal avrl = loss / period;
    decimal rs = gain / loss;
    rsi[period] = 100m - (100m / (1m + rs));

    for (int i = period + 1; i < price.Length; ++i)
    {
        var diff = price[i] - price[i - 1];

        if (diff >= 0)
        {
            avrg = ((avrg * (period - 1)) + diff) / period;
            avrl = (avrl * (period - 1)) / period;
        }
        else
        {
            avrl = ((avrl * (period - 1)) - diff) / period;
            avrg = (avrg * (period - 1)) / period;
        }

        rs = avrg / avrl;

        rsi[i] = 100m - (100m / (1m + rs));
    }

    return rsi;
}
```

#### Edit:

I did it myself. The only thing left is to calculate the RSI (CalculateRSI) without having to recalculate everything. I know I have to backup the gain/loss but not sure how to do it yet. The reason is because if I have to do that again and again for each new price, which takes a lot of time and I won't be able to catch up on web socket event trigger.

```
// New code
var stochs = new decimal[prices.Length];

var rsi = CalculateRSI(prices, 14);
var highestHigh = CalculateHighest(rsi, 9);
var lowestLow = CalculateLowest(rsi, 9);

// Helpers
public decimal[] CalculateHighest(decimal[] prices, int period)
{
    var highest = new decimal[prices.Length];

    highest[0] = prices[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < period; ++i)
    {
        if (prices[i] > highest[i - 1])
        {
            highest[i] = prices[i];
        }
        else
        {
            highest[i] = highest[i - 1];
        }
    }

    int highestIdx = 0;

    for (int i = period; i < prices.Length; ++i)
    {
        decimal highestHigh = decimal.MinValue;
        var start = Math.Max(i - period + 1, highestIdx);
        for (int s = start; s <= i; ++s)
        {
            if (prices[s] > highestHigh)
            {
                highestHigh = prices[s];
                highestIdx = s;
            }
        }

        highest[i] = highestHigh;
    }

    return highest;
}

public decimal[] CalculateLowest(decimal[] prices, int period)
{
    var lowest = new decimal[prices.Length];

    lowest[0] = prices[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < period; ++i)
    {
        if (prices[i] < lowest[i - 1])
        {
            lowest[i] = prices[i];
        }
        else
        {
            lowest[i] = lowest[i - 1];
        }
    }

    int lowestIdx = 0;

    for (int i = period; i < prices.Length; ++i)
    {
        decimal lowestLow = decimal.MaxValue;
        var start = Math.Max(i - period + 1, lowestIdx);
        for (int s = start; s <= i; ++s)
        {
            if (prices[s] < lowestLow)
            {
                lowestLow = prices[s];
                lowestIdx = s;
            }
        }

        lowest[i] = lowestLow;
    }

    return lowest;
}
```

Comment: _decimal[] rsi = ..._ - please don't elide code; we should see the full code for review.

Comment: @Reinderien, it's a decimal[] of RSI values. I pasted the formula for it.

Comment: You are ignoring first value from rsi array: `for (int i = 1; i < price.Length; ++i)` and then `rsis.Insert(0, rsi[i]);` This is by design?

Comment: @Peska, Binance did it that way. Probably not by design, because everyone calculates the RSI this way.

Comment: @Peska, this one is a bit more clear: https://github.com/michaelcostabr/IndicatorsBot/blob/master/IndicatorsBot.Core/Indicators/RSI.cs, not sure if their output is the same (haven't tested it).

Comment: `decimal[] rsi = ...` should still be replaced by the actual call. Don't make us guess. We'll do it wrong, you get a useless answer and we've wasted our time.

Comment: @Mast, I did that part myself. You can see my edit. The only part left is to make the `CalculateRSI` method not recalculate everything (all prices) everytime I add a new price. Something like an additional method "Recalculate(decimal price)` which can be useful when a new price is added. It has to backup the sum somehow.